# Changing Swiper pagination depending on media query

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

Here is the problem.
I am using swiper. I need progressbar pagination on mobile media queries, and bullets pagination on tablet and desktop media queries. Breakpoints work, but if the media query is being changed dinamicly, the pagination doesnt work correctly. You have to refresh the page.
I been told, that I should use slider.update() with breakpointchecker. But It doesn't work. Perhaps, I used it not correctly. How should I use swiper.update in this situation? Here is my code below:

```html
import {swiper} from '../vendor/swiper';

const breakpointSm = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)');

const clientsSlider = () => {
  const clientsSliderElem = document.querySelectorAll('.clients-slider__list');

  if (!clientsSliderElem) {
    return;
  }
 
  const clientsSliderSettings = {
    autoheight: false,

    pagination: {
      el: '.clients-slider__pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.slider-controls-btn--next',
      prevEl: '.slider-controls-btn--prev',
      disabledClass: 'slider-controls-btn--disabled',
    },

    breakpoints: {
      1368: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        slidesPerColumn: 2,
        slidesPerColumnFill: 'row',
        slidesPerGroup: 4,
      },
      1023: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        slidesPerColumn: 2,
        slidesPerGroup: 3,
      },
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        slidesPerColumn: 2,
        slidesPerGroup: 2,
      },
      320: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        slidesPerColumn: 2,
        pagination: {
          el: '.clients-slider__pagination',
          progressbarFillClass: 'clients-slider__progressbar',
          type: 'progressbar',
        },
      },
    },

 
    slideClass: 'clients-slider__item',
    slideActiveClass: 'clients-slider__item--active',
    slideNextClass: 'clients-slider__item--next',
    slidePrevClass: 'clients-slider__item--prev',
    slideVisibleClass: 'clients-slider__item--visible',
    wrapperClass: 'clients-slider__wrap',
  };


  clientsSliderElem.forEach((slider) => {
    const mySwiper = new Swiper(slider, clientsSliderSettings);

    const breakpointChecker = () => {
      if (breakpointSm.matches) {
        mySwiper.update();
      }
    };

    breakpointSm.addListener(breakpointChecker);

    breakpointChecker();
  });
};


export {clientsSlider};
```